# How to use AWS Glue Job Bookmarking with concurrent runs for s3 source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My requirement is I have a file with say 100 records, I want to process 20 records in 5 concurrent runs. How to achieve this?

Comment: Glue job bookmark works on file-level so you can't use it to keep track on record-level.